# Meteor adding custom fields to Meteor.users : should I do it?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, scalability

I am creating a web service using Meteor.

I am designing the model, and I have stumbled across a difficult problem: Mongo is not designed to work with joins. However, I must logically associate a user with a subscription (which is an object that has many properties in it).

Therefore, my question is this:

Should I embed the subscription model into the Meteor.users collection, or should I create a new collection called "Subscriptions" and fight my way through manual joins? The reason why I am hesitant to use the first solution is that Meteor.users is a collection that is being handled by Meteor's Accounts and Password frameworks. Sure, you can embed a "profile" object upon creation, but how is this method going to scale up afterwards?

I would appreciate any insights on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the Meteor.users collection to store custom data all the time, there's nothing to prevent you from modifying it by adding additional fields, just keep in mind the following:

1. There are certain fields Meteor treats specially, be careful not to break them.
2. By default a user is only allowed to see their own profile, username and id, you'll need to write your own publication if you want the user to be able to see other fields, such as a custom 'subscriptions' collection.
3. Several of the Meteor used fields are security sensitive, when writing logic to allow a user to update subscriptions you need to take care that you don't allow a user to edit those fields.

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users

**Update:**

I'm not entirely sure about the performance implications of adding subscriptions to a user record, since I don't know exactly what you're going to store in the subscription, or how you want to use that data. We tend to use user specific subscriptions a lot in our apps, eg:

```
Meteor.publish({
 'userSubscriptions': function () {
   return Subscriptions.find({userId: this.userId});
 }
})
```